# Grammatical mistake

Tags: grammar, british-english

The following sentence does not make much sense to me. I'm confused whether there's any error. Is there a grammatical error in the sentence:

```
"To these are added this."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is an error. It should read: "To these ***is*** added this." The form of the verb "to be" used here needs to be the singular "is," instead of "are," which is plural.